I cannot modify a field for a var struct pointer in Zig
const std = @import("std");

pub fn main() void {
    var u = &User{ .id = 2 };
    u.id = 54;
}

const User = struct { id: i32 };

The above code gives me the following error, the variable is declared using the var modifier yet it says cannot assign to constant.
main.zig:5:6: error: cannot assign to constant
    u.id = 54;
    ~^~~
referenced by:
    callMain: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/zig/0.12.0/lib/zig/std/start.zig:501:17
    callMainWithArgs: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/zig/0.12.0/lib/zig/std/start.zig:469:12
    remaining reference traces hidden; use '-freference-trace' to see all reference traces



In this case, u is *const User.
You can add @compileLog(@TypeOf(u)); to check the type. The compiler prints:
Compile Log Output:
@as(type, *const main.User)

You need to have a non-constant User instance, then you can take a pointer to it. Like this:
const std = @import("std");

pub fn main() void {
    var user = User{ .id = 2 };
    var ptr = &user;
    ptr.id = 54;
}

const User = struct { id: i32 };

